# REGEX: findall complete tag a with target parameter in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem and I'm a noob in regex. I try everything but I don't know how can remove this

```
text = '<a href="https://url1.com/q234243/" target="_blank">la orden  texto, texto ,texto jurídicas del bla bla bla que obliga a la corporación que rige al  tenis bla bla bla, el patrocinador de sus principales asuntos y<a href="https://url2.com/124345w23/" target="_blank"> el dictamen de texto random y mas texto random apu, que se han convertido en uno de los rammstein es la ostia económicos de la actividad, al punto de'
```

I need to obtain the a tags as follows using re.findall()

```
urls = ['<a href="https://url1.com/q234243/" target="_blank">',
        '<a href="https://url2.com/124345w23/" target="_blank">']
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: or if you have just strings, use builtin functions to find/replace

Comment: `<a[^>]*>` will match what you asked for, but as other comment suggested, better to use an HTML parser where possible. Also a note that your example doesn't have closing anchor tag.. is that deliberate? `<\/?a[^>]*>` will also match for the closing tags.

Comment: thanks @CrayonViolent, as you said the example don't have closing anchor tag, that's the reason of why I can't use HTML parser, but this regex is super cool to solve the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "this is why I can't use html package" - that is incorrect. HTMLParser will parse any tag whether it comes from valid html, or not. It will go over everything and find some kind of place for it, no matter how malformed it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use regex:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)',text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) to easily get your data, regardless of how malformed it is. In this example we overwrite `feed` and `handle_starttag` to customize them for your needs. This module is very simple and straight-forward. A quick trip through the docs and you can make this do whatever you want. This is the same parser package that is often used as the second argument for `BeautifulSoup`, and when it is, this is the parser that `BeautifulSoup` uses.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

text = '<a href="https://url1.com/q234243/" target="_blank">la orden  texto, texto ,texto jurídicas del bla bla bla que obliga a la corporación que rige al  tenis bla bla bla, el patrocinador de sus principales asuntos y<a href="https://url2.com/124345w23/" target="_blank"> el dictamen de texto random y mas texto random apu, que se han convertido en uno de los rammstein es la ostia económicos de la actividad, al punto de'

class Parser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)

        self.anchors = []
        
    def feed(self, html:str) -> list:
        super().feed(html)
        return self.anchors
        
    def handle_starttag(self, tag:str, attrs:list) -> None:
        if tag == 'a':
            self.anchors.append(self.get_starttag_text())
            
            
parser  = Parser()
anchors = parser.feed(text)
```

results

```
['<a href="https://url1.com/q234243/" target="_blank">', 
'<a href="https://url2.com/124345w23/" target="_blank">']
```